# how to add pine script in trading view widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, tradingview-api, indicator

when adding pine script in tradingview widget in my react js project. that's throw error
413 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: Oa-3nqtcBC5j1OghOYAtCTEnOVn71kOZd7tIzEN1DB9CpnXtr_WzyQ==

> 

```
 useEffect(
        () => {
            chartRef.current = createWidget;
            const CustomPineScript = ` //@version=5
// pine script to display price trading levels on tradingview
//
// To hide the inputs options from the chart, go to "Chart settings", "Status line", and deselect "Indicator arguments"

indicator("Price Trading Levels", "", true)

// inputs //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

inMajorColor = input(color.fuchsia, "", group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "1")
inMajorStyleOption = input.string("─────", title="", options=["─────", "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", "⋯⋯⋯"], group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "1")
inMajorWidth = input.int(4, "", 1, 9, 1, group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "1")
inMajorShow = input.bool(true, "", tooltip="Major Price levels. (1,2,3,5,8...)", group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "1")

inMediumColor = input(color.orange, "", group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "2")
inMediumStyleOption = input.string("─────", title="", options=["─────", "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", "⋯⋯⋯"], group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "2")
inMediumWidth = input.int(3, "", 1, 9, 1, group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "2")
inMediumShow = input.bool(true, "", tooltip="Medium Price levels. (50% between each major levels)", group="Major & Medium Levels", inline = "2")

inMinorColor = input(color.teal, "", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "3")
inMinorStyleOption = input.string("⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", title="", options=["─────", "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", "⋯⋯⋯"], group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "3")
inMinorWidth = input.int(2, "", 1, 9, 1, group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "3")
inMinorShow = input.bool(true, "", tooltip="Minor Price levels, 0.1", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "3")

inMicroColor = input(color.olive, "", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "4")
inMicroStyleOption = input.string("⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", title="", options=["─────", "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", "⋯⋯⋯"], group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "4")
inMicroWidth = input.int(1, "", 1, 9, 1, group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "4")
inMicroShow = input.bool(true, "", tooltip="Micro Price Sublevels, 0.01", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "4")

inNanoColor = input(color.aqua, "", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "5")
inNanoStyleOption = input.string("⋯⋯⋯", title="", options=["─────", "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", "⋯⋯⋯"], group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "5")
inNanoWidth = input.int(2, "", 1, 9, 1, group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "5")
inNanoShow = input.bool(true, "", tooltip="Nano Price Sublevels, 0.001", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "5")

inPicoColor = input(color.gray, "", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "6")
inPicoStyleOption = input.string("⋯⋯⋯", title="", options=["─────", "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃", "⋯⋯⋯"], group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "6")
inPicoWidth = input.int(1, "", 1, 9, 1, group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "6")
inPicoShow = input.bool(true, "", tooltip="Pico Price Sublevels, 0.0001", group="Minor & Sublevels", inline = "6")

inAutoSublevels = input.bool(true, "Auto Hide Minor & Sublevels", tooltip="Auto hide levels if the 'spread / price scale' ratio is greater than these values. Select 'Show Debug Info' to find the right ratio for your needs.", group="Auto Hide Minor & Sublevels", inline = "7")
inAutoDisplayMinor = input.float(5.0000, "Minor", 1.0, 10.0, 0.1, group="Auto Hide Minor & Sublevels", inline = "8")
inAutoDisplayMicro = input.float(0.5000, "Micro", 0.1, 0.9, 0.01, group="Auto Hide Minor & Sublevels", inline = "8")
inAutoDisplayNano = input.float(0.0500, "Nano", 0.01, 0.09, 0.001, group="Auto Hide Minor & Sublevels", inline = "9")
inAutoDisplayPico = input.float(0.00500, "Pico", 0.001, 0.009, 0.0001, group="Auto Hide Minor & Sublevels", inline = "9")

inLabelsShow = input.bool(true, "Show Price Labels", tooltip="")
inDebugShow = input.bool(false, "Show Debug Info")


// convert line style "string" to "line.style" type
inMajorStyle  = inMajorStyleOption  == "⋯⋯⋯" ? line.style_dotted : inMajorStyleOption  == "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃" ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid
inMediumStyle = inMediumStyleOption == "⋯⋯⋯" ? line.style_dotted : inMediumStyleOption == "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃" ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid
inMinorStyle  = inMinorStyleOption  == "⋯⋯⋯" ? line.style_dotted : inMinorStyleOption  == "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃" ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid
inMicroStyle  = inMicroStyleOption  == "⋯⋯⋯" ? line.style_dotted : inMicroStyleOption  == "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃" ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid
inNanoStyle   = inNanoStyleOption   == "⋯⋯⋯" ? line.style_dotted : inNanoStyleOption   == "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃" ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid
inPicoStyle   = inPicoStyleOption   == "⋯⋯⋯" ? line.style_dotted : inPicoStyleOption   == "⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃⁃" ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid


// constants ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var float[] majorFiboLevels = array.from(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0, 80.0, 100)
var float[] mediumFiboLevels = array.from(1.5, 2.5, 4.0, 6.5, 9.0, 11.50, 16.50)
var float[] minorFiboLevels = array.from(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.5, 7.2, 8.0)
var float[] thirdteenLevels = array.from(0.13, 13, 13000)

// number of bars to the "left visible bar"
int bars = ta.barssince(time == chart.left_visible_bar_time)

// level labels "x" position
int level_label_x = chart.left_visible_bar_time + (20 * (time - time[1]))


// functions ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// return highest visible price
getChartHigh(src, len) =>
    max_bars_back(src,600)
    max = src[0]
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] > max
            max := src[i]
    max

// return lowest visible price
getChartLow(src, len) =>
    max_bars_back(src,600)
    min = src[0]
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] < min
            min := src[i]
    min

// return rounded value
// int precision: 1, 10, 100...
// string type: ceil, floor or round
getRound(value, precision, type) =>
    if type == "ceil"
        math.ceil(value / precision) * precision
    else if type == "floor"
        math.floor(value / precision) * precision
    else if type == "round"
        math.round(value / precision) * precision
    else
        na


// return scale for number
getScale(number) =>
    scale = 0.0
    if number < 0.0001
        scale := 0.00001
    else if number < 0.001
        scale := 0.0001
    else if number < 0.01
        scale := 0.001
    else if number < 0.1
        scale := 0.01
    else if number < 1
        scale := 0.1
    else if number < 10
        scale := 1
    else if number < 100
        scale := 10
    else if number < 1000
        scale := 100
    else if number < 10000
        scale := 1000
    else if number < 100000
        scale := 10000
    else if number < 1000000
        scale := 100000
    scale



// vars /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// chart visible highest price
float chart_high = getChartHigh(high, bars)

// chart visible lowest price
float chart_low = getChartLow(low, bars)

// rounded low & high
chart_low_rnd = float(getRound(chart_low, getScale(chart_low), "floor"))
chart_high_rnd = float(getRound(chart_high, getScale(chart_high), "ceil"))

// chart limit (display some levels above, and under, high / low)
chart_low_limit = chart_low-getScale(chart_high-chart_low)*0.33
chart_high_limit = chart_high+getScale(chart_high-chart_low)*0.33

// scale of price. (0.1, 1, 10, 100...)
price_scale = getScale(chart_low_rnd)
high_price_scale = getScale(chart_high_rnd)



// print lines and labels functions /////////////////////////////////////////////

printLine(_price, _color, _style, _width) =>
    if _price >= chart_low_limit and _price <= chart_high_limit
        _line = line.new(last_bar_index-1, _price, last_bar_index, _price, color=_color, style=_style, width=_width, extend=extend.both)


printLabel(_price, _color) =>
    if _price >= chart_low_limit and _price <= chart_high_limit
        _label = label.new(level_label_x, _price, text=str.tostring(_price), textcolor=_color, color=chart.bg_color, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal, xloc=xloc.bar_time)


printMinorLevels(_price, _scale, _color, _style, _width) =>
    for ratio in minorFiboLevels
        level_price = _price + (_scale * ratio)
        if not array.includes(majorFiboLevels, (level_price/price_scale)) and not array.includes(majorFiboLevels, (level_price/high_price_scale)) and not array.includes(thirdteenLevels, level_price) and not array.includes(mediumFiboLevels, (level_price/price_scale)) and not array.includes(mediumFiboLevels, (level_price/high_price_scale))
            printLine(level_price, _color, _style, _width)
            if inLabelsShow
                printLabel(level_price, _color)


// debug /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if inDebugShow and barstate.islast

    ln_high = line.new(last_bar_index-1, chart_high, last_bar_index, chart_high, color=color.green, extend=extend.both)
    lb_high_text = "chart_high = "+str.tostring(chart_high)+"\nchart_high_rnd ="+str.tostring(chart_high_rnd)
    lb_high = label.new(bar_index-9, chart_high, lb_high_text, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, textalign=text.align_left)

    ln_low = line.new(last_bar_index-1, chart_low, last_bar_index, chart_low, color=color.red, extend=extend.both)
    lb_low_text = "chart_low = "+str.tostring(chart_low)+"\nchart_low_rnd ="+str.tostring(chart_low_rnd)
    lb_low = label.new(bar_index-9, chart_low, lb_low_text, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, textalign=text.align_left)

    lb_text = "base_price = " + str.tostring(chart_low_rnd) + "\nprice scale = " + str.tostring(getScale(chart_low_rnd)) + "\nchart_high_rnd scale = " + str.tostring(getScale(chart_high_rnd)) + "\nchart_low_rnd scale = " + str.tostring(getScale(chart_low_rnd)) + "\nspread = " + str.tostring(chart_high-chart_low) + "\nspread/price_scale = " + str.tostring((chart_high-chart_low)/price_scale) + "\nbars = " + str.tostring(bars)
    
    lb_debug = label.new(bar_index-9, chart_high, lb_text, textcolor=color.white, color=color.blue, style=label.style_label_up, textalign=text.align_left)



// Trading levels lines and labels ///////////////////////////////////////////////
if barstate.islast

    // major & medium levels loop
    for base_price = (chart_low_rnd - price_scale) to chart_high_rnd by (price_scale*0.1)

        // major levels
        if inMajorShow and (array.includes(majorFiboLevels, (base_price/price_scale)) or array.includes(majorFiboLevels, (base_price/high_price_scale)) or array.includes(thirdteenLevels, base_price))
            printLine(base_price, inMajorColor, inMajorStyle, inMajorWidth)
            if inLabelsShow
                printLabel(base_price, inMajorColor)

        // medium levels
        else if inMediumShow and (array.includes(mediumFiboLevels, (base_price/price_scale)) or array.includes(mediumFiboLevels, (base_price/high_price_scale)))
            printLine(base_price, inMediumColor, inMediumStyle, inMediumWidth)
            if inLabelsShow
                printLabel(base_price, inMediumColor)


    // minor and sublevels loop
    low_scale=getScale(chart_low)
    scales = array.from(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1)
    for sc in scales
        lshow = false
        lcolor = inMinorColor
        lstyle = inMinorStyle
        lwidth = inMinorWidth

        if sc == 0.0001
            if not inAutoSublevels or (chart_high-chart_low)/price_scale < inAutoDisplayPico
                lshow := inPicoShow
                lcolor := inPicoColor
                lstyle := inPicoStyle
                lwidth := inPicoWidth
        else if sc == 0.001
            if not inAutoSublevels or (chart_high-chart_low)/price_scale < inAutoDisplayNano
                lshow := inNanoShow
                lcolor := inNanoColor
                lstyle := inNanoStyle
                lwidth := inNanoWidth
        else if sc == 0.01
            if not inAutoSublevels or (chart_high-chart_low)/price_scale < inAutoDisplayMicro
                lshow := inMicroShow
                lcolor := inMicroColor
                lstyle := inMicroStyle
                lwidth := inMicroWidth
        else if sc == 0.1
            if not inAutoSublevels or (chart_high-chart_low)/price_scale < inAutoDisplayMinor
                lshow := inMinorShow
                lcolor := inMinorColor
                lstyle := inMinorStyle
                lwidth := inMinorWidth

        if lshow
            base_price = chart_low_rnd - price_scale
            while base_price <= chart_high
                printMinorLevels(base_price, low_scale*sc, lcolor, lstyle, lwidth)
                base_price += low_scale*(sc/0.1)`
            if (!tvScriptLoadingPromise) {
                tvScriptLoadingPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
                    const script = document.createElement('script');

                    script.id = 'tradingview-widget-loading-script';
                    script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js';
                    script.type = 'text/javascript';
                    script.onload = resolve;
                    document.head.appendChild(script);
                });
            }
            tvScriptLoadingPromise.then(() => chartRef.current && chartRef.current());


            function createWidget() {
                if (document.getElementById('tradingview_ac040') && 'TradingView' in window) {
                    setChartLoader(false)
                    new window.TradingView.widget({
                        autosize: true,
                        symbol: stockCode,
                        theme: "dark",
                        style: "1",
                        locale: "en",
                        toolbar_bg: "#f1f3f6",
                        // enable_publishing: true,
                        // withdateranges: true,
                        range: "YTD",
                        hide_side_toolbar: false,
                        allow_symbol_change: false,
                        enabled_features: ["move_logo_to_main_pane"],
                        // hide_legend: true,
                        details: true,
                        studies: [
                            "ElliottWave@tv-basicstudies",
                        ],
                        source: 'https://www.tradingview.com/script/XvS9Lamf-Price-Trading-Levels/',
                        overrides: {
                            'paneProperties.background': '#131722',
                            'paneProperties.vertGridProperties.color': '#363c4e',
                            'paneProperties.horzGridProperties.color': '#363c4e',
                            'scalesProperties.textColor': '#AAA',
                            'mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.upColor': '#00FF00',
                            'mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.downColor': '#FF0000',
                            'mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.drawWick': true,
                            'mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.drawBorder': true,
                            // Add your custom Pine Script code here
                            'mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.pineScript.code': CustomPineScript,
                        },
                        show_popup_button: true,
                        container_id: "tradingview_ac040"

                    });
                    // return () => {
                    //     widget.remove();
                    // };
                }
            }
            // document.querySelector('.tv-header__link').remove();
        }, [stockCode]);
```